# Overlapping multiple div using CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

**I'm trying to create a design using multiple divs using CSS**.

I'm already written code for it but don't know what is the problem with my code as my **left and right side div** not aligning at vertically center and all the divs are **not overlapped** with **main yellow** centered div which is I'm unable to achieve.

**Note:** I tried this with  `z-index` but did not get what I want.

**Output I'm getting:**

[image]

**Output I want to achieve:**

[image]

**My code :**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title></title>
</head>
<style>
  .maind {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: rgb(9, 252, 9);
    position: relative;
  }

  .fdiv {
    margin: auto;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(10, 233, 222);
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
  }

  .sdiv {
    width: 55%;

    height: 600px;
    background-color: #ffff00ec;

  }

  .tdiv {
    margin: auto;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(10, 233, 222);
    border: 2px solid red;
  }

  p {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;

  }

  .wr1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(10, 233, 222);
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
</style>
<body>
<div class="maind">

  <div class="fdiv">
    <p>Some content here...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wr1">
      <p>Some content here..</p>

    </div>
    <div class="sdiv">
      <p>Some content here..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wr1">
      Some content here...
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tdiv">
    <p>Some content here..</p>
  </div>





</div>




</body>

</html>
```

Please somebody help me with the **Source Code** I tried almost all the related answer.

Comment: Change margin, or translate from their original position. Use ```position: absolute``` on each child elements to arrange them with respect to the position of their parent element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like following snippet, with absolute positioning:

```css
.maind {
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 90%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: rgb(9, 252, 9);
    position: relative;
  }

  .fdiv {
    margin: auto;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(10, 233, 222);
    margin-top: 30px;
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 35%;
    z-index: 22;
  }

  .sdiv {
    width: 80%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 10%;
    left: 10%;
    height: 600px;
    background-color: #ffff00ec;
    z-index: 12;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }

  .tdiv {
    margin: auto;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(10, 233, 222);
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 20%;
    left: 35%;
    z-index: 22;
  }

  p {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    
  }

  .wr1 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(10, 233, 222);
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 22;
  }
  .wr2 {
    width: 25%;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: rgb(10, 233, 222);
    border: 2px solid red;
    position: absolute;
    top: 35%;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 22;
  }
```

```html
<div class="maind">

  <div class="fdiv">
    <p>Top...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="wrap">
    <div class="wr1">
      <p>Left..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="sdiv">
      <p>Somessss content here..</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wr2">
      <p>Right...</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tdiv">
    <p>Bottom..</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Flexbox` or `Positioning`. 
Using `Positioning` makes it more flexible to add content to the **holder** element. 
While `Flexbox` is more flexible when it's about adding and aligning `boxes`.

### # Positioning

#### Description:

Create *4* elements to **be** the boxes. 
Each `.box` has it's *direction*.

Example: `<div class="box top"></div>`.

Wrap all of them in `div.boxes`. This way you can separate the `.box`es from the content (if there) in the **holder**,

```
<div class="boxes">
    <div class="box top"></div>
    <div class="box right"></div>
    <div class="box left"></div>
    <div class="box bottom"></div>
</div>
```

Style the the `position` of `.wrapper` so all the `positioned absolute` elements stays in the `.wrapper`.

```
.wrapper {position: relative;}
```

Finally, set the position of each `box`: 
Example:

```
.box.top {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top: -40px;
}
```

#### Notes:

Don't use:

- `left` **property** on `.box.right`.
- `top` **property** on `.box.bottom`.

It won't set the **negative margin** which pushes them to edges.

- In case content added to the holder (`.wrapper`), wrap the content in `div.content` and add **inner** space using `padding`. The value of `padding` in the code example is `40px`, which it's related to the `.box`es *dimenstions*.
  The space (`padding`) is added to prevent `overflow` between `content` and `.boxes`es. And we can go further with styling the `.box`es with `overflow` and `z-index` property.

**For more about using negative maring and the boxes dimenstions**:
Check for **Notes** in **Flexbox**

#### The Code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 50px auto;
}

.box {
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: red;
}

.box.top, .box.bottom {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
}

.box.left, .box.right {
    width: 80px;
    height: 200px;
} 

.box.top {
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.box.bottom {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.box.left {
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-left: -40px;
}

.box.right {
    right: 0;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    margin-right: -40px;
}

.content {
    padding: 40px; /* check notes */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="boxes">
        <div class="box top"></div>
        <div class="box right"></div>
        <div class="box left"></div>
        <div class="box bottom"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

### # Flexbox

##### Description:

Create *3* elements to hold the `.box`es. 
`top`: holding *top* box
`center`: holding *left* and *right* boxes
`bottom`: holding *bottom* box

In other words:

- Each `.box` is nested (a child) in a `div` that has the `class` of the *direction*.

Example: `<div class="top">BOX</div>`.

- Left and right are nested in `center`.

HTML:

```
<!-- top box -->
<div class="top">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>

<!-- left, right boxes -->
<div class="center">
    <div class="left">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- bottom box -->
<div class="bottom">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Wrap all of them in a `div.wrapper`:

```
<div class="wrapper">
     <!-- top box -->
     <div class="top"></div>
     <!-- left, right boxes -->
     <div class="center"></div>
     <!-- bottom box -->
     <div class="bottom"></div>
</div>
```

The lines below will style the *3* elements and set them to their positions, `.top` will be centered (left right) and on *top*, `.center` will be *centered* from all the directions, `.bottom` is centered (left right) and at the *bottom*, by displaying the `.wrapper` `children` horizontally (`flex-direction: column;`) and centered (`align-items: center;`) with (`space-between`) them, using `flex`.

**Check:** [A Complete Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Then we do something similar with the `.center` element, by displaying both of `left` and `right` next to each other, centered and `space-between` them.
(No `flex-direction` property in the declaration, since the default is in a row (vertically))

```
.wrapper .center {
    width: 100%; /* Don't delete, check notes */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

And finally, with **negative** `margin` we move the `boxes` to the edges.

```
.top .box {
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.bottom .box {
    margin-bottom: -40px;
}

.center .left .box {
    margin-left: -40px;
}

.center .right .box {
    margin-right: -40px;
}
```

#### Notes:

The `left` and `right` *boxes* are (`width: 80px`), each, which means the `margin` should be `-40px` (80 / 2 = 40) to set on center.

- `left`: `margin-left: -40px`
- `right`: `margin-right: -40px`

Same for `top` and `bottom`, since the *dimensions* are flipped.

- `top`: `margin-top: -40px`
- `bottom`: `margin-bottom: -40px`

This way, all the `boxes` are gonna be centered at the edges.

- By default, when displaying with `flexbox`, the parent(`.center`) will take the `width` of it's content/children (fitted)! which means, `width: 40px * 2`, since we have *2* boxes in there. Now to make sure that the `space-between` value works, we should "stretch" the `.center` element (parent) by styling it's `width` to `100%` which allows to the `box`es to have as much as `space-between`, then every `box` is gonna be on it's *position*.

```
.wrapper .center {
    width: 100%; /* Don't delete, check notes */
}
```

#### The Code:

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
    border: 1px solid;
    max-width: 600px;
    min-height: 600px;
    margin: 60px auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.box {
    border: 1px solid;
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper .top .box,
.wrapper .bottom .box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 80px;
}

.wrapper .center .box {
    width: 80px;
    height: 200px;
}

.top .box {
    margin-top: -40px;
}

.bottom .box {
    margin-bottom:-40px;
}

.wrapper .center {
    width: 100%; /* Don't delete, check notes */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}

.center .left .box {
    margin-left: -40px;
}

.center .right .box {
    margin-right: -40px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="top">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="center">
        <div class="left">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="box"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottom">
        <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

#### EDIT:

As @anatolhiman  mentioned in the comments:

> but negative margins will create a problem by having the elements
> overflowing right and left (especially on narrow screens).

A **simple** solution:
(same works for both examples)

*wrap* the *HTML* that we added before in another `div`, `.container` for example, and add spacing with CSS, either `padding` or `margin` works, depends on your situation.

So the question is...
Is it a space **within** the `.container`? --> `padding`. 
Or **outside** of it? --> `margin`.

Give the `.container` a `background-color`, resize the window, and check both `margin` and `padding` to see the differences.

HTML - Update:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="wrapper">

     </div>
</div>
```

CSS - Add:

```
/* outside space */
.container {margin: 50px;}

/* Or */

/* inside space */
.container {padding: 50px;}
```

- You may have to edit the `margin` property in `.wrapper` for `top bottom`.
- Extra space added (`50px`) to include spaces for the `.box`es as well.
- Remember: `.wrapper{max-width: VALUE}` is taking a place in this functionality, since it's `max-width` is X but it could be smaller. So if the property is `width:` and **not** `max-width` then it'll behave differently, and won't work **as expected** (fully responsive), unless we use [@media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media) or **JavaScript**.

Comment: Good answer, but negative margins will create a problem by having the elements overflowing right and left (especially on narrow screens). For this to work we have to ask @Nishant if he plans to use the wrapper as the outermost element on the page, or if maybe the whole setup can be placed inside another wrapper that has sufficiently padding/margin/size to avoid the red boxes from falling off the sides of the page.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I don't know but somehow I forgot about ```margin: -40```